# laravel seeding returns undefined index

Tags: mysql, laravel, seeding

I have got this migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name_en')->default('');
        $table->string('name_de')->default('');
        $table->string('alpha_2')->default('');
        $table->string('alpha_3')->default('');
    });
}
```

and this seeder

```
$countries = [
            0 => [
                "name_en" => 'Afghanistan',
                "name_de" => 'Afghanistan',
                "alpha_2" => 'af',
                "alpha_3" => 'afg'
            ],
            1 => [
                "name_en" => 'Albania',
                "name_de" => 'Albanien',
                "alpha_2_en" => 'al',
                "alpha_3_en" => 'alb',
            ],
            2 => [
                "name_en" => 'Algeria',
                "name_de" => 'Algerien',
                "alpha_2_en" => 'dz',
                "alpha_3_en" => 'dza',
            ] ......
```

and then ill run it like:

```
foreach ($countries as $arr) {

            DB::table('countries')->insert([
                'name_en' => $arr['name_en'],
                'name_de' => $arr['name_de'],
                'alpha_2' => $arr['alpha_2'],
                'alpha_3' => $arr['alpha_3']
            ]);
        }
```

the weird thing is, that it does indeed seed the first row Afghanistan with all entries, but it returns an error saying that "Undefined index: alpha_2"
i have not a single clue why, if i remove alpha_2 and alpha_3 it works, i even tried changing the names because maybe alpha is a restricted word, no luck until now.
Any idea why ? :/

Comment: You're using `alpha_2_en` and `alpha_3_en` in your second, third ... elements.

Comment: oh man, thank you very much..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have index name `alpha_2_en` and `alpha_3_en` in your second and third elements of `countries` array. And then you are trying to use those index like `alpha_2` and `alpha_3` in the foreach loop. That's causing the error. Update your `countries` array.

```
$countries = [
            0 => [
                "name_en" => 'Afghanistan',
                "name_de" => 'Afghanistan',
                "alpha_2" => 'af',
                "alpha_3" => 'afg'
            ],
            1 => [
                "name_en" => 'Albania',
                "name_de" => 'Albanien',
                "alpha_2" => 'al',
                "alpha_3" => 'alb',
            ],
            2 => [
                "name_en" => 'Algeria',
                "name_de" => 'Algerien',
                "alpha_2" => 'dz',
                "alpha_3" => 'dza',
            ] ......
```